# Unhandled exception issue after throwing my custom exception class

Tags: flutter, try-catch

I am throwing my HttpException but its not reaching  `on HttpException catch` and honestly I dont know what is a problem.

Here is my custom HttpException class:

```
class HttpException implements Exception {
  final String message;

  HttpException(this.message);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return message;
    // return super.toString(); // Instance of HttpException
  }
}
```

and here are my try catch blocks:

this one is in provider within login and signup method:

```
try{
      final response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode({
        'email': email,
        'password': password,
        'returnSecureToken': true
      }));
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      if (responseData['error'] != null) {
        throw HttpException(responseData['error']['message']);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return Future.error(error);
    }
  }
```

and here I want to catch my HttpException but my code didnt reach this.

```
try{
      if (_authMode == AuthMode.Login) {
        // Log user in
        await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).login(_authData['email'], _authData['password']);
      } else {
        // Sign user up
        await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).signup(_authData['email'], _authData['password']);
      }
    } on HttpException catch (error) {
      var errorMessage = 'Authentication failed';
      if (error.toString().contains('EMAIL_EXISTS')) {
        errorMessage = 'This email address is already in use';
      } else if(error.toString().contains('INVALID_EMAIL')) {
        errorMessage = 'Its not a valid email';
      } else if(error.toString().contains('WEAK_PASSWORD')){
        errorMessage = 'This password is too weak';
      } else if(error.toString().contains('EMAIL_NOT_FOUND')){
        errorMessage = 'Could not find that email';
      } else if(error.toString().contains('INVALID_PASSWORD')){
        errorMessage = 'Invalid password';
      }
      _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
    } catch (error) {
      var errorMessage = 'Could not authenticate you, please try again later';
      _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
    }
```

I checked this in debugger, my error message is for example: 'EMAIL_EXISTS' but instead of dialog I have this error in console:
`Unhandled Exception: EMAIL_EXISTS`

Comment: are you sure that code which returns your `Future` is properly `await`ed?

Comment: Yeah, I checked it right now, it is looking properly

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```dart
return Future.error(HttpException(responseData['error']['message']));
```

try

```dart
throw HttpException(responseData['error']['message']);
```

Replace return with throw as Exceptions need to be `thrown`
And the `Future.error()` is caught with `.catchError()`

Comment: I had this earlier, its still the same behaviour

Comment: What's your output exactly?

Comment: `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: EMAIL_NOT_FOUND`